# Manu on verse 8.33 on stealing lost property

Tags: scripture, dharma-shastras, manu-smriti, punishment

As per **Manu 8.33** it states, *"Property that has been lost and found should remain in the charge of specially deputed (officials); and the thieves that he may detect in connection with this, the king shall cause to be killed by an elephant."*
[[Source]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200930.html)
In the same verse Medhatithi states, *"The specification of the ‘elephant’ can only he with a view to some invisible (transcendental) result."* There are some errors regarding copying of grammar from source to verse in wisdom.lib, but does this mean that this particular verse was metaphorical, and does this have greater implications on punishments of Manu?